# How to convert scatter plot into a surface plot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Beginner using python and I have a scatter plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQNHM.png).  What I want to do is produce a 3D plot that shows a spike in the Z direction at these points and 0 everywhere else.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
plt.scatter(X, Y) 
plt.show()

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = [1] * len(X)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

This gives me a strange result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fLeT.png) that I'm not sure what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to use the x and y values from your 2D plot as the input for meshgrid because you want this plot to be defined for all integer values of x and y in your range. The original x and y should define the location of the spikes if I understand your problem correctly. Here's a way to get a 3D plot with spikes of height 100 at defined locations:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create X, Y and Z arrays
x = range(0,250)
y = range(0,250)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.zeros((250,250))
# Locations of the spikes. These are some made up numbers. 
dataX = np.array([25,80,90,145,180])
dataY = np.array([170,32,130,10,88])
# Set spikes to 100
Z[dataX,dataY] = 100
# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to modify this so that it also works when x and y aren't integers?